# Sharepoint-moved document is acessible by old link but takes time(up to 3hrs)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, sharepoint-addin

After moving a document from one location to other, The old link(link with doc id) is taking some time (up to 3hrs) to work.Could anyone please say,what is reason behind it, or how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the search having to do a crawl before the new location is picked up.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559302(v=office.14).aspx :

SharePoint Server 2010 takes a two-part approach when the document ID service looks up document IDs to provide the best balance of document IDs that work immediately and those that work across broad scopes:

- Search. Find an item across any location that belongs to the current
  search scope. Search generally performs better as a cross-list query.
  However, search is only as reliable as its last index. Therefore, if
  an item was added but has not yet been indexed by search, it does not
  appear in search results. Additionally, if an item was moved since
  the last time it was indexed by search, then the old (and now broken)
  URL appears in search results.
- Lookup specific to the ID provider.    When an item cannot be
  retrieved by using search (for example, if it    has not been indexed
  yet), SharePoint Server 2010 calls back to the    document ID
  provider and allows it to use its own lookup logic. This    enables
  providers who want to use IDs that work before search    indexing is
  run on the last items to look them up. The provider    determines
  whether to perform lookups in this way and what the most    effective
  logic is for doing so.

As you can see, the search is the default tool SharePoint uses to locate documents based on a document ID